# UILabel not updating inside dispatch_group_notify

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, grand-central-dispatch

Why is this not working?

```
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) { () -> Void in
    println("Howdy, I get called")
    self.myLabel.text = "Hello Mr. Gordon Freeman"
}
```

The message is printed but the UILabel text is not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must only update UI elements from the main queue:

```
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    println("Howdy, I get called")
    self.myLabel.text = "Hello Mr. Gordon Freeman"
}
```